# Django: rendering a model object as an image/icon

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following two Django models:

```py
class ProjectType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey("ProjectType", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The `ProjectType` object would be things like: "research", "outreach", "administrative", etc.

What I'd like to do is render `ProjectType` as a standardized icon (ex.: a little beaker representing "research" projects). Perhaps using a method?

For instance, having the following line in an HTML template:

```
{{ projet.project_type.as_icon }}
```

And rendering it as:

```html
<img src="images/beaker_icon.png"/>
```

Is this possible? Can I give the class method instructions on how to render images? If so, would this be a best practice?

Comment: Is that `breaker_icon` different per `ProjectType`, if yes, what determines the path?

Comment: Yes it would be a different path for each `ProjectType`. I suppose it would be a property of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this

```py
class ProjectType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)

    def get_icon(self):
        if self.name == "research":
            return '<img src="images/beaker_icon.png">'
        elif self.name -- 'outreach':
            return '<img src="images/some_other_icon.png">'
```

and in the html, use:

```
{{ project.project_type.get_icon | safe }}
```

## OR

If you are ok to save your icon file path somewhere as media, you could have something like this.

Have a model to save standard icon files.

```py
class StandardIcon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=<path>, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can then add this to Django admin and upload your icons with the name field as `research`, `outreach`, etc

And in your `ProjectType` model you could have

```py
class ProjectType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)

    def get_icon(self):
        try:
            logo = StandardIcon.objects.get(name=self.name).logo:
            return logo
        except StandardIcon.DoesNotExist:
            return ""
```

and then use

```
<img src="{{ project.project_type.get_icon }}">
```

This is more secure since you control the database inputs, file uploads and are not sending html strings to html doc.